# Pronunciation of "tous"?

Tags: prononciation

I was listening to a podcast and the speaker (a native of France) pronounced the *s* at the end of *tous* in this sentence, pronouncing it as *tousse*:

> Nous sommes tous partis en voiture pour le centre-ville.

In which there is obviously no liaison.

Explanation?? Just an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *s* at the end of *tous* is always pronounced when *tous* is used as a pronoun. Some examples:

- J'avais invité cinq amis, tous sont venus.
- Venez tous !
- Tous les mêmes !
- Du travail pour tous

---

Regarding “*tous les*”, in most cases this is used as the English would “all the X”. For example, “tous les invités applaudirent” means “(all (the guests)) applauded”, where parenthesis indicate levels of grouping.

On the other hand, “*tous les mêmes*” is different: it implies “*ce sont* tous les mêmes”, “they are all the same”, in which *tous* is actually an adjective.

Comment: In the duplicate question, all the adjective examples are of the form *Tous les [something]*. Why is *tous les mêmes* different? Or is one of the two answers wrong somehow?

Comment: Perfect, thanks.